# How do I find something in a text file that is before a character

Tags: python, file, text

I have a text file and it has a company name before a dash "-" I want to find that company name example: TELSTRA - EV 12M FWD

I have only found a way to access the dash

```
import re
hand = open('Companies.txt')
content = hand.read()
hand.close()
for line in content:
    if re.search('  -', line) :
        print(line)
```

I expect the output to be TELSTRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `re.findall` here, with the pattern `(\S+)(?=\s*-)`:

```
input = "TELSTRA - EV 12M FWD"
matches = re.findall(r'(\S+)(?=\s*-)', input)
print(matches)
```

This outputs:

```
['TELSTRA']
```

Comment: Oh that makes sense THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Use split function. It will result to a list and get the first item of that list.

```
import re
hand = open('Companies.txt')
content = hand.readlines()
hand.close()
for line in content:
    print(line.split('-')[0])
```

Result:
         TELSTRA

Comment: It actully prints out
"T
E
L
S
T
R
A"

Comment: because you should use readlines() rather than read. Read will take each individual string while readline will read per line. See my updated answer.